# Jersey: GrizzlyWebContainerFactory is missing in Jersey 1.9.1

Tags: web-services, jersey

I'm getting started learning Jersey by following the [tutorial](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#getting-started)

From Main class of the tutorial

```
       System.out.println("Starting grizzly...");
       SelectorThread threadSelector = GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.create(BASE_URI, initParams);
```

My problem is the GrizzlyWebContainerFactory is not exist for me. From the example, the class is at `com.sun.jersey.api.container.grizzly.GrizzlyWebContainerFactory` but I cannot find it in any jars. What am I missing here? Or they refactored it to another class?

Note: My class path includes:     `grizzly-servlet-webserver.jar, jersey-server.jar, jersey-core.jar, jsr311-api.jar, asm.jar`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3a%22com.sun.jersey.api.container.grizzly.GrizzlyWebContainerFactory%22), you're looking for [com.sun.jersey:jersey-grizzly:1.9.1](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.sun.jersey%7Cjersey-grizzly%7C1.9.1%7Cbundle)